# Python read in string from file and split it into values

Tags: python, file, split

I have a file in the format below:

```
995957,16833579
995959,16777241
995960,16829368
995961,50431654
```

I want to read in each line but split the values into the appropriate values. For example the first line would be split into:

```
x = 995957
y = 16833579
```

Since its a string when you read it in and I want to convert them to an int and split them, how exactly would I go about doing this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Something like this - for each line read into string variable `a`:

```
>>> a = "123,456"
>>> b = a.split(",")
>>> b
['123', '456']
>>> c = [int(e) for e in b]
>>> c
[123, 456]
>>> x, y = c
>>> x
123
>>> y
456
```

Now you can do what is necessary with `x` and `y` as assigned, which are integers.

Comment: `map(int, a.split(","))` is cool

Answer (score 18):

I would do something like:

```
filename = "mynumbers.txt"
mynumbers = []
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        mynumbers.append([int(n) for n in line.strip().split(',')])
for pair in mynumbers:
    try:
        x,y = pair[0],pair[1]
        # Do Something with x and y
    except IndexError:
        print "A line in the file doesn't have enough entries."
```

The with open is recommended in http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html since it makes sure files are closed correctly even if an exception is raised during the processing.

Answer (score 12):

Use `open(file, mode)` for files. 
The mode is a variant of 'r' for read, 'w' for write, and possibly 'b' appended (e.g., 'rb') to open binary files. See the link below.

Use `open` with `readline()` or `readlines()`. The former will return a line at a time, while the latter returns a list of the lines.

Use `split(delimiter)` to split on the comma.

Lastly, you need to cast each item to an integer: `int(foo)`. You'll probably want to surround your cast with a try block followed by `except ValueError` as in the link below.

You can also use 'multiple assignment' to assign a and b at once:

```
>>>a, b = map(int, "2342342,2234234".split(","))  
>>>print a  
2342342
>>>type(a)  
<type 'int'>
```

[python io docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

[python casting](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/interesting-casting-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> [[int(i) for i in line.strip().split(',')] for line in open('input.txt').readlines()]
[[995957, 16833579], [995959, 16777241], [995960, 16829368], [995961, 50431654]]
```