# Split every word in line by comma, then store entire line in list

Tags: python

I was wanting to read in a file which has 4 values on each line:
title, author, genre, price.

I want to split each value which has a ',' as the delimiter. Then I want to save it to my List each line being an entry in the list. For example

```
title, author, genre, price

title2, author2, genre2, price2
```

This will save as

```
List[0][1] = title 
List[0][2] = author 
List[0][3] = genre 
List[0][4] = price

List[1][1] = title2
List[1][2] = author2 
List[1][3] = genre2 
List[1][4] = price2
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def readFile(fileName):
List = []
f = open(fileName, 'r')
line = f.readline()
x = 0
while len(line) != 0:
    for i in range(4):
        List[x][i] = line.split(',')
    x += 1
    line = f.readline()
f.close()
return List
```

But I'm just getting `List index out of range`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python read in string from file and split it into values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857731/python-read-in-string-from-file-and-split-it-into-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has you covered here, just use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

def readFile(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        return list(reader)
```

Your code makes several classical errors:

- `str.split()` returns a list; you are trying to assign that list 4 times to indices of another list. Just use the list returned by `str.split()` directly.
- Take into account that lines from a file come with the line-separator (`\n`) included; you probably want to strip that off first.
- You started with an *empty* list. You can't assign to indices that are not there, use `list.append()` instead to add elements.
- You don't need to test for `len(line) != 0`; just `if line:` is enough because empty strings are considered 'false' in a truth test. See [*Truth Value Testing*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).
- You don't need to use `file.readline()` each time; just use a `for line in f:` loop and you'll get each line one by one, because file objects are *iterable*.
- If you use your [file as a context manager](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) (by using the `with` statement), Python will close the file for you.

So, without the `csv` module, you could write your code like this:

```
def readFile(fileName):
    rows = []
    with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            columns = line.strip().split(',')
            rows.append(columns)
    return rows
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not allowed to use modules - I should have specified that. It's for classwork.

Comment: @Ryan: I was already writing out everything that needed correcting in your code.

Comment: Thank you - That's so much cleaner and more efficient than what I've been doing. The explanations really helped too!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the Python [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), to achieve the your function with less code .

```
def readFile(fileName):
    with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
        List = [line.strip().split(',') for line in f if line.strip()]
    return List
```

The program above is equivalent to the following program:

```
def readFile2(fileName):
    with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
        List = []
        for line in f:
            if line.strip():
                List.append(line.strip().split(','))
    return List
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   with open(filname,'r') as f:
        lst_data = f.readlines()

    List = []
    for data in lst_data:
        List.append(data.strip().split(','))
```

List will have the data like this

```
List[0][1] = title 
List[0][2] = author 
List[0][3] = genre 
List[0][4] = price

List[1][1] = title2
List[1][2] = author2 
List[1][3] = genre2 
List[1][4] = price2
```