# Working with coordinates/arrays

Tags: python-2.7, arraylist, coordinates

I have a text file with coordinates

> x1 y1 z1
>
> x2 y2 z2

Now I want to know at which `y-coordinate` the `value` of x exceeds a specific point. How do I do that?

As a first step I tried using a `function` with `list`s:

```
def coordinates(dataset):

    x = np.array(0)
    y = np.array(0)
    z = np.array(0)

    dataset = open(dataset,'r')

    dataset = line.strip()
    dataset = line.split()

    i=0
    while i<10:
        x = np.append(x,float(line[0]))
        y = np.append(y,float(line[1]))
        z = np.append(y,float(line[2]))
        i+=1

    print x
    return x,y
```

(I used `print x` to check the results at the terminal)
When using the `function` it seems `line.split()` only uses the last line and splits it. So the result at the terminal is `[0  x10 x10 x10 x10 x10 x10 ...]`.

Does anyone know how to fix it? Or is there any other/better solution?

Comment: Not a python crack, but from the control flow: you need to read one line, split it, parse it, read next line, split it, .... - doubt your code does this, alternativly read all lines into an array and split each part of the array. No part of the code checks any "Exceed" mechanics. Have a look at Kens answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857731/python-read-in-string-from-file-and-split-it-into-values for howto read lines/split

Comment: Thanks! Kens answer helped a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.loadtxt` function. After you have all your coordinates in three arrays

```
from io import StringIO 
import numpy as np

### simulates your input file
c = StringIO("0 1 2 \n 3 4 5 \n 6 7 8")

d=np.loadtxt(c) # file readout into a 2D array
x=d[:,0]        # gets x coordinate array
y=d[:,1]
z=d[:,2]

print (x)
print (y)
print (z)
###

xQ = 3.5                       # your "exceed" coordinate
print (y[x>xQ][0])             # returns the first y value where x>xQ
```

The last line uses that `[x>xQ]` is in fact a boolean mask array that we can apply onto other coordinates, `y` in your case.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot!